# python multithreaded server recieves two requests from browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm attempting to create a simple threaded server in python. When making a call in a browser it seems that two requests are made, which cause the script to error.

I can add additional checks to `urlparse` but I would prefer to prevent this second call from occurring.

I wondered if it was my PHP script, so have used postman to send the request and still have the same issue.

Update: On adding a break after the final send the loop obviously stops. Whats odd is the first request seems to fail then every other request the client has the correct data.

```
class ClientThread(Thread): 

    def __init__(self,ip,port): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.ip = ip 
        self.port = port 

    def run(self): 

        while True :
            data = conn.recv(2048) 

            // it errors here stating index out of range. 
            // I can add checks, but would like to prevent/not detect this seccond request
            parsed_url = urlparse(data.split()[1].decode("utf-8"))

            dctParams = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)

            if "ProductID" in dctParams:
                sProductID = dctParams.get("ProductID")[0]
            else:
                print("Unable to find key. Continuing")
                break #continue

            print("Requested ProductID: ", sProductID, "found. Attempting to find matches")

            bSuccess = True

            try:
                aOut = data_matrix.loc[sProductID].nlargest(10)
                print("Request satisfied")
                print(aOut)
                print("\n\n")
            except:
                bSuccess = False
                print("Error Finding product in data set")

            byt = ""

            if bSuccess:
                byt = json.dumps({'Success': True, 'Data': aOut.to_dict()}).encode("utf-8")

            else:
                byt = json.dumps({'Success': False, 'Data': ''}).encode("utf-8")

            # send headers
            conn.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n'.encode("utf-8"))
            conn.send("Content-Type: application/json\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
            sLenth = "Content-Length: " + str(len(byt))
            sLenth += "\r\n\r\n"
            conn.send(sLenth.encode("utf-8"))

            # send the acutal json
            conn.send(byt)


# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0' 
TCP_PORT = 12345 
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Usually 1024, but we need quick response 

tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)) 
threads = [] 

while True: 
    tcpServer.listen(4) 
    print("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...\n\r")
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept() 
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port) 
    newthread.start() 
    threads.append(newthread) 

for t in threads: 
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the two requests? No, I'll tell you one of them is for the index and the other is for the favorite icon.

You can not prevent the browser from making any potential unwanted requests all you can do is respond to them with the appropriate response code.